# Matrix multiplication with an array of matrices

Tags: r, arrays, matrix-multiplication

I have an array of matrices, `Z1`, and a matrix, `Z2`. `Z1`, has dimension `[25,2,4]` and `Z2` has dimension `[2,10]`.

I would like to perform `Z1[,,i]%*%Z2` for `i = 1,2,3,4`. Is this possible using sweep of apply?

I can do this using a for loop and do not want to do that here.

An example of the proposed data: `Z1 = array(1:200, dim = c(25,2,4));
Z2 = array(1:20, dim = c(2,10))`

Comment: `lapply(1:4,function(i) Z1[,, i] %*% Z2) `

Comment: lapply and sapply (although you have to do a little rearranging after with sapply) are both options. But, they are essentially wrappers that run for loops. 

Is there a way to use apply or sweep or something else that does not "do a for loop".

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you want to avoid the for loop (or wrappers of a for loop) because it is slow?

Comment: @bzki Yes. The arrays and dataframes that I am dealing with are much larger and I am hoping to limit the number of for loops when possible.

Comment: This seems to be a question about performance, at which point you wouldn't gain much from using `apply`. It is similarly just a glorified `for-loop`. compiling the overall and intermediate functions might give quite a boost however (eg. `FUN <- compiler::cmpfun( FUN ); FUN(...)`).

Comment: @Oliver I am not so familiar with the compiler::cmpfun syntax. Are you able to write a solution to the above problem by using your suggestion?

Comment: Hello @Lee, i dont have the time to go in-depth. `compiler` is a package (comes with `R`), and the function `cmpfun` takes a single function and bit-compiles it. Every package function will be bit-compiled by default, and it helps with standard calls to `R` functions, and if your case contains a lot of R code it can help speed it up. `for-loops` are especially good cases of situations where it helps. An example is simple `fn <- function(x) {for(i in 1:10000) do-something}; fn <- cmpfun(fn);`, after which it is compiled and will work as normal.

Comment: So basic usage: wrap your code in a function `my_function <- cmpfun(function(){ all your code })` and use it as you would any other function. If you have multiple functions simply wrap them in the `cmpfun`. For every day code this is not necessary, but sometimes code can see a large boost. Sometimes the boost is minimal. It depends on the function. (i might make an example in an answer if i get some time, but don't count it.)